# Is it possible to dynamically add output properties to an angular 2 component?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am on my way to create my own angular 2 module which I called **angular2-actionable-table**.

The goal of this module is to provide a generic table to use when we want to make some actions on some data. (for example: we can use this module to create a CRUD table).

I begin with writing some simple typescript classes.

```
export class Column{
  constructor(public name: string) {
  }
}

export class Action {
  constructor(public name: string) {
  }
}
```

And the component class.

```
import {Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {Action} from "./models/action.model";
import {Column} from "./models/column.model";

@Component({
   selector: 'app-angular2-actionable-table',
   templateUrl: './angular2-actionable-table.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./angular2-actionable-table.component.css']
})
export class Angular2ActionableTableComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() columns: Column[];
  @Input() actions:Action[];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```

So the client of this module can make this

```
<app-angular2-actionable-table [columns]="columns" [actions]="actions"></app-angular2-actionable-table>
```

What I want to do in the **Angular2ActionableTableComponent** is to dynamically add output properties according to the **columns** attribute. In other words, let's say the client has passed as input value this `columns = [new Action('edit'), new Action('validate')]`. So I want to make something similar to this in the **Angular2ActionableTableComponent**

```
for(let i=0; i<this.columns.length; i++){
  @Output() Angular2ActionableTableComponent.prototype[this.columns[i].name];
  // The syntax is wrong for sure
}
```

And then after emitting events to each action, the client can do this

```
<app-angular2-actionable-table [columns]="columns" [actions]="actions"
    (edit)="onEdit($event)" (validate)="onValidate($event)">
</app-angular2-actionable-table>
```

I am not sure if this is possible in Angular 2 using Typescript.

Comment: Interesting question. Emitting a generic `onEvent()` event to which you would pass an object containing some kind of event identifier (`edit`, `validate`...) is not an option?

Comment: @AngularFrance good option, and I have already thought about that, but I still want to know if it is possible to add output properties dynamically, that would be a great option instead.